# How to prove that this multivariable polynomial quotientring is a field, and to what field is it isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I’m studying abstract algebra for my finals and I have a question. I’m asked to show that the quotientring underneath is a field.

$$ \frac{\mathbb{Z} \left[ X, Y \right]}{(5, XY-Y+6, Y-X^2)}$$

Due to the correspondence theorem we can quotient out sequentially, such that we get:

$$ \frac{\mathbb{Z}_5 \left[ X, Y \right]}{(XY+4Y+1, Y-X^2)}$$

Where the ideal now also lies in $\mathbb{Z}_5 \left[ X, Y \right]$. Then I quotient out by $Y-X^2$, such that the ring is isomorphic (via the first isomorphism theorem) to:

$$ \frac{\mathbb{Z}_5 \left[ X, X^2 \right]}{(X^3+4X^2+1)} \cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}_5 \left[ X \right]}{(X^3+4X^2+1)} $$

Now $\mathbb{Z}_5[X]$ is a PID and the ideal between brackets is not maximal, because the polynomial is reducible in $\mathbb{Z}_5$, so the quotientring can't be a field.
Where have I gone wrong in my approach, if it is completely faulty, how should I approach these type of questions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Indeed $2$ is a root, so the quotient has zero divisors. Maybe there is a typo, or this is a "trick question"?

Comment: You are completely right: the displayed quotient ring is not a field, exactly because of the computation that you show. Bravo.

Comment: This might be a typo, i.e., $XY+Y+6$ instead. Then the quotient  $\Bbb F_5[x]/(x^3+x^2+1)$ is a field, because the cubic is irreducible over $\Bbb F_5$. Do you have a scan of your old exam, to check?

Comment: Whether there's a typo or not, your approach is exactly right...

Comment: The old exam was uploaded to our student website, but it’s written in latex by students themselves. It is diplayed like I typed it, so it’s probably a typo then. Thanks for the replies!